# Flink throws NOSUCHMETHOD ERROR when i tried to read form kafka

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to read from kafka and apache flink throws this error...how can i fix it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQESb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually NoSuchMethod come from versioning problems. Update your pom/gradle dependencies so that they match the version of Flink / Java / Scala you are using to run the job.